# Hadoop MapReduce :java.io.EOFException: Premature EOF: no length prefix available

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, eofexception

when I try the Example: WordCount v1.0 from

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v1.0

I got the warns and Exceptions blow:

[image]

And I found that when I put some .txt files to the HDFS. I also got the EOFException. Anyone know why ?

Comment: You should check the health of your cluster. The error message says you have a bad data node.

Comment: How to check it and I checked with command 'jps', all datanode work.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have write permission to the destination directory. Once I got the permission, it worked fine. Error was deceiving.